# How to make an iPhone TimeTable App

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

I want to create an Iphone App to view my gym's timetable, I am learning objective C at the moment. It is a simple app to view the timetable for now .

The Interface a `UITableView` with a Header (Time of the day) and static Left row that show the day of the week, the data (gym  classes info) on the middle so the user can scroll right/left and up/down.

Something like: "Sky App on the Iphone" http://www.ko-muaythai.com/appview.jpg (I can't upload images yet.)

I know how to load data on my `UITableView` using `JSON` and I am following a tutorial from

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1  to make horizontal tables,

But I need some guidance regarding how to make Header and the Left row, I dont know where to start.

Comment: I have done something similar for a festival application which shows the schedule (which bands plays when) for the festival. What I did was to use a scroll view and layout the schedule myself. Then, if you want the left side column, you could use to scroll views and send any scroll events applied to one scroll view to the other. Thereby the left column will respond to up and down scroll events but not left and right scroll events as it's content size will not exceed the width of the scroll view.

Comment: Simon did you used Nib or storyboard ?

Comment: Not really. I set up a basic layout containing only a navigation bar, a button on the navigation bar and a scroll view. Then I added my schedule to this scroll view programmatically as there are a lot of calculations on the length of each concert (or in your case, lession), their position relative to the timeline and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have static header and left side column, I would create two seperate view controllers one for header and one for left column and place them in main view controller(as sub views) where you have universal scroll-able tiles View controller.

Comment: ok so i need to look into how to add subviews over the main UITableviewController and how do you position the subview on the main view ? Thankss

Comment: I am not sure how to do using storyboard, but we can either do this programmatically by setting the coordinates to frame and then add sub view or through Interface Builder nib files. http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/29/creating-a-view-programmatically/